# LANG environment variable not respected

Tags: linux-mint, environment-variables, i18n

OS: Mint13

I have set my preferred language to zh-cn via the language support option.

This has changed the language of a small handful of things (synaptic, dates and times).

However everything else is still in English.

When i set my LANG and MDM_LANG variables to zh-CN.UTF-8 manually in the terminal, and open an application - the correct language is displayed.

However even having placed `export LANG="zh-CN.UTF-8"` and `export LANG="zh-CN.UTF-8"` in my `.bashrc` everything is still in English. (even if run from the terminal which reports the correct LANG etc).

EDIT:

```
~ $ locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

~ $ cat /etc/environment
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="zh_CN:en_AU:en"
LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Definitely try .utf8 (lower case no dash). I'm on my phone right now so I can't test, but I remember having to use `en_US.utf8` just the other day.

Comment: I think you can use .UTF-8 and .utf8 interchangeably, at least here both work, and `locale -a` only shows `.utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're slightly off on the name of your locale. Try `export LANG=zh_CN` or `export LANG=zh_CN.utf8`.

To find out list of valid locales look in `/usr/share/locales`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed now (via a full restart). btw I think that all the `zh` locales have caps for UTF - I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try reconfiguring you locales running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Exporting `LANG` on `.bashrc` will only affect applications started from a terminal.

Alternatively you can edit as root the file `/etc/default/locale` but make sure the locales you need are present, by running `locale -a`.

Comment: `/etc/default/locale` has zh-CN as the first language for all options, as does `/etc/environment/` and yet this doesn't filter through to `locales`. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Changing locales requires a full restart.

Comment: Locales or any other kind of change involving environment variables or groups, if you don't start with those set, changing files won't magically make everything inherit the new values. Also, special care should be taken if you use something like a graphical login manager, as I wonder if that won't simply bypass anything like shell initialization files and just start the X process straight away.

Comment: @njsg Yeah I thought that a logout / login would be enough - especially as that did actually change the date and time language

Comment: That depends on the distro. On Gentoo, you need to regenerate the `/etc/profile` (more correctly, files sourced by it), and after you do that, any login shell will get the new locale settings. And you can always source `/etc/profile` on a running shell. Now for, say, getting the new locale on the X process, you need to start X from an environment with the new locales (here I'd have to terminate X, source `/etc/profile` and run startx again). You can use `locale` to inspect what are the locale settings in a specific shell you are using.

Comment: (In fact, if you're curious, play with it -- you can, given that you have these locales installed (`locale -a` to get a list of installed locales), run commands with different locales, for example, in GNU bash `LC_TIME=pt_PT.utf8 date` gives me the portuguese date format. You can also start programs with different UI languages, if they support these and don't choose to ignore the locale settings (I think libreoffice does this for some measurement and currency settings...): `LANG=fi_FI.utf8 libreoffice` gives me LibreOffice with a Finnish UI.)